# Is there a way to decrypt a plain text which was encrypted with AES

Tags: javascript

I've tried a few things and haven't managed to find a way to do so, I've been searching for a few hours now and got no where.

I encrypted the text serverside with AES and sent the key and the encrypted message back to be decrypted clientside. I'm doing this for practice.

this is my current code which doesn't work whatsoever

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Servlet",
    success: function (key) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Servlet2",
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log("key - " + key);
                console.log("encrypted - " + msg);
                console.log({ciphertext: msg});
                var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: msg}, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
                console.log("decrypted - " + decrypted);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I know I'm supposed to feed it a ciphertext but I have no clue how to convert the plain String to an actual ciphertext.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I encrypted the text serverside with AES and sent the key and the encrypted message back to be decrypted clientside." Why?

Comment: for practice reasons, no real reason.

Answer (score 1):

**Sending secret key to client-side to decrypt a text is definitely an anti-pattern and you don't want to do that.**

But if for some reason you still want to (again, you better not), seems like your syntax is not correct.

This line

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: msg}, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

should be:

```
// first argument to `.decrypt` is the message itself, not an object
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(msg, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Comment: that's what it originally was haha, it didn't work so I tried a few other things. also I realize I shouldn't be doing this I'm just building up from the basics and wanted to know how to do this.